# AngularJS page 404s

Tags: angularjs

I've been adding content to an Angular project I inherited. However the new pages I've added only work when the links to them are clicked. Inputting the URL directly or refreshing the page results in a 404. These pages are included in the route provider, app.js, and manifest.json. The pages are linked in the navigation bar like this

`<a href="/settings" ng-click="setPage('settings')">Settings</a>`

The setPage function just highlights the current tab in the navbar and collapses it if necessary. Did I miss something?

Comment: What server-side technology are you using? You need to set up a wildcard route in your server `/angular_app_url/*` so that it is picked up by the same controller. From there angular's routing can take over.

Comment: do older parts of app refresh properly?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, they do